# What kind of info are there in the first 832 bytes of .so file?

Tags: elf, strace

I saw many similar stuff like this:

```
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260W \0242\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
```

What's there in the beginning 832 bytes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format and there are links to more authoritative references at the bottom of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @mu is too short ,sorry,but I don't find the answer there,`ELF` can contain lots of things,I just want to know which of them are being looked up.

Answer (score 3):

If the listing above was captured at program startup, then it is
likely that you are seeing the runtime loader in action, as it brings
in shared libraries and resolves symbols prior to launching the
program.

As for the initial contents being read, every ELF file starts with an
ELF header which describes the layout and contents of the rest of the
file---please see the tutorial "[libelf by Example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/files/Documentation/libelf-by-example/20101106/)" for more
information.

Comment: so the ELF header is always less than `832` bytes?

Comment: Yes: Elf32_Ehdr is 52 bytes long; Elf64_Ehdr is 64 bytes. As to why it reads 832 bytes, and not just 64; the answer is here: http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/elf/dl-load.c#l111